# CSS - Two dropdown's joining error

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

The problem is in this image link right below:

[Image for Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRTXd.png)

As you can see, there are two arrows as there are two dropdowns. Can I give a space between them so they don't look that bad..?

The HTML Code is:

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="text3">Request for:</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name=category id=category class="text">
      <option value='' selected>Select one</option>
      <?Php require "config.php";// connection to database $sql="select * from category " ; // Query to collect data foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) { echo "
      <option value=$row[cat_id]>$row[category]</option>"; } ?>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <select name=sub-category id=sub-category class="text"></select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The CSS Code is:

```
.text {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
  transition: 500ms all ease;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.text:hover {
  box-shadow: 12px 13px 0px rgba(204, 211, 51, 0.38), -11px -14px 0px rgba(241, 96, 0, 0.28), 18px -24px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34), 33px -6px 0px rgba(39, 74, 214, 0.28);
}
```

Comment: That's not HTML. When you post questions like this, don't post `PHP` code, post the generated HTML instead.

Comment: and thanks a lot B-Lat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a margin to your text class, for example:

```
margin: 2px;
```